# Is the CSR included in the keystore?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I have generated a csr and keystore using the following command.

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore <keystore_name> -dname "<domain_name>" && keytool -certreq -alias server -file <csr_name> -keystore <keystore_name>
```

The certificate site says

> "A CSR is an encoded file that provides you with a standardized way to send us your public key along with some information that identifies your company and domain name."

Will the CSR be a part of keystore ? If it's not, then what is the use of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSR means certificate signing request and is used to get a signed certificate from a certificate authority without giving them access to your private key itself. The CSR file contains public part of the key together with the identifying information about the certificate. You'll send it to certificate authority and they can create a signed public certificate for you based on the data in CSR.

Afterwards, you can import the received public certificate to your keystore where you have the matching private key to sign documents or enable secure connection to your server.